# Swift5 filter list with 2 match strings

Tags: arrays, swift, swift5, array-filter

I have an array of JSON in my swift5 application.
So I want to filter the array in base of a string field of this array. So I'm build this code:

This code is working

```
self.array = self.arrayFull({$o["status"].stringValue == "Pending"})
```

But I need to have a list with status == "Pending" or status == "Process"

What I should do to apply the filter on these 2 strings?

**EDIT**

The original code is:

```
//get all orders result by web service 
self.arrListAll = swiftyJsonVar["result"].arrayValue 
//filter the orders where status is Pending or Process 
self.arrListPending = self.arrListAll.filter({$0["status"].stringValue == self.st_pending || $0["status"].stringValue == self.st_driver_rejected})
```

This code works.
But now to get the information of this array I must to use dictonary structure to get the value of this array for example:

```
let dic = arrListPending[indexPath.row]
let arr_productDetail = dic["item_data"].arrayValue
let strName = arr_productDetail.map({$0["item_name"].stringValue})
```

now I want to transform this dictionary array to Object array.

Comment: It's unclear, did you meant: `self.arrayFull { ["Pending", "Process"].contains($0["status"].stringValue == "Pending"}) }`?

Comment: the Web service, return a list of Orders. This order can have different status. In this mode I create a new list with only order where status is PENDING or PROCESS.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `self.arrayFull { ["Pending", "Process"].contains($0["status"].stringValue) }`

Comment: The original code is:
//get all orders result by web service
self.arrListAll  = swiftyJsonVar["result"].arrayValue
//filter the orders where status is Pending or Process
self.arrListPending =  self.arrListAll.filter({$0["status"].stringValue == self.st_pending || $0["status"].stringValue == self.st_driver_rejected})

This code works. But now to get the information of this array I m costrict to use dictonary structure to get the value of this array, now I want to trasform this dictionary array to Object array

Comment: Edit your question with that code instead of in comment when it's hard to read

Comment: Just edit my question

Comment: That's a Swift question? Or JavaScript one? What's the link between the two?$

Comment: all code is swift code

Comment: Then why is this question tagged with JavaScript and not swift?

Comment: Also why not just add `.values` to the last line of the code labeled "The original code"?

Comment: The structure of what's inside `arrListPending` is unclear and I don't understand what you want in the end. Because `arr_productDetail` being an array, I don't understand the map, since then `strName` should be an array of String.

Comment: Also, following your other questions, since I guess you managed to get a custom Codable structure instead of playing with SwiftyJSON, you might want to update your question.

Comment: @bircastri Is this question still relevant? Is your model using custom struct (ViewModel, or at least Codable struct) instead of playing with Dictionary, Array, and SwiftyJSON? If yes, what's the new code and structures?

Answer (score 0):

In order to check whether any value from an array of values matches a particular string, use the Array.contains Swift method. Using your original code, it would look like this:

```swift
//get all orders result by web service
self.arrListAll = swiftyJsonVar["result"].arrayValue
//define status values to filter for
let status_values = ["Pending", "Process"]
//filter the orders where status matches any defined in status_values
self.arrListPending = self.arrListAll.filter({status_values.contains($0["status"].stringValue)})
```

This ideology sets up an array of values, and then uses the `filter` method to filter for only values that exist in the array. For example:

```swift
let filter_values = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let filtered_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter({ filter_values.contains($0) })
dump(filtered_values) // -> [4, 5]
```

This outputs the values `4` and `5` because those are the only value from the input array that match values included in the defined in `filter_values`.

Here are the official documentation links for both the `filter` and `contains` Array.methods in Swift:

- **Filter:** [filter(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter)
- **Contains:** [contains(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains)